# Vim tags file hidden

Tags: c++, c, vim, ctags

When I type `ctags -R .` it produces a file called tags, and vim uses that file to navigate tags. How do I make the file name to be .tags and make vim use it?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=vim+ctags

Comment: The default name is `tags`. Consider leaving it as it is. Why is having the file not hidden a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to specify the name of the `tags` file is explained very early in `$ man ctags`:

```
$ ctags -Rf .tags .
```

How to tell Vim where to look for `tags` files is explained in `:help 'tags'` (and linked sections). A good *generic* default value is:

```
set tags=./tags;,tags;
```

Since you want `.tags` instead of `tags` you should add that case to the value above (safe and somewhat universal):

```
set tags=./tags;,tags;./.tags;,.tags;
```

or only use a value that fits *your* usage pattern:

```
set tags=./.tags;,.tags;
```

Comment: Related: [automatically running `ctags` from `git`](http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html).  You can move the `tags` file to the `.git` directory.  You can make Vim aware of it with something like this: `exec 'set tags+=' . findfile('.git/tags', ';')`.